# Rao-Blackwell's Theorem for uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

> Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be iid from a uniform distribution
>    $U[\theta-\frac{1}{2}, \theta+\frac{1}{2}]$ with $\theta \in
>  \mathbb{R}$ unknown. Take for granted that $T(\mathbf{X}) =
>  (X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ is minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$ and consider the unbiased estimator $\overline{X}$. Apply Rao-Blackwell's Theorem and find the estimator that improves upon $\overline{X}$ by conditioning on $T$.

My attempt: Let $\phi(T) = E(\overline{X}|T)$. By Rao-Blackwell's Theorem, $\phi(T)$ is a uniformly better unbiased estimator of $\theta$ than $\overline{X}$. However, how can I find an expression for this estimator?

My initial idea: To compute the expectation, I will need to find the conditional distribution of $\overline{X}$ given $T$ (which ofcourse does not depend on $\theta$ since $T$ is sufficient). I have found the joint distribution of $T= (X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ which is given by

\begin{align*}
f_{X_{(1)}, X_{(n)}}(x_{(1)}, x_{(n)}) = \begin{cases} n(n-1)(x_{(n)} - x_{(1)})^{n-2} & \text{ if } \theta-\frac{1}{2} < x_{(1)} < x_{(n)} < \theta+\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}.
\end{align*}

If I can somehow find the joint distribution of $\overline{X}$ and $T$, then I should be able to find the conditional distribution and then compute the conditional expectation.

Is this the right approach? If so, how can I find the joint distribution of $\overline{X}$ and $T$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2001780/321264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the first step is to choose an arbitrary $X_i$.

Note that

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& \hspace{15pt} E(X_i \ | \ X_{(1)} = l, \ X_{(n)} = u) \\
& = E(X_i \ |\  X_{(1)} = l, \ X_{(n)} = u, \ X_{i} = l) * P(X_i = X_{(1)}) \\
& + \ E(X_i \ | \ X_{(1)} = l, \ X_{(n)} = u, \ X_i = u) * P(X_i = X_{(n)})  \\
& + \ E(X_i \ | \ X_{(1)} = l, \ X_{(n)} = u, \ l < X_i < u) * P (X_i \neq X_{(1)}, X_i \neq X_{(n)}) \\
& = l*\frac{1}{n}+u*\frac{1}{n}+\frac{l+u}{2}*\frac{n-2}{n} \\
&= \frac{(l + u)}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Now just apply the linearity of expectation to get that $E(\bar{X} \ | \ X_{(1)}, X_{(n)}) = \frac{X_{(1)} + X_{(n)}}{2}$

Edit: tweaked to make it clear that we are consider the probability $X_i$ is equal to the order statistic.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. I just have a few questions. Why isn't $P(X_i = X_{(1)}) = 0$? Since $X_i$ is a continuous random variable, isn't the probability of a single point always $0$? Also, how is the expectation $E(X_i | X_{(1)}=l, X_{(n)}=u, l<X_i<u)=\frac{l+u}{2}$? I can see how you obtain the answer, that is, the conditional distribution of $X_i$ given $X_{(1)}=l, X_{(n)}=u, l<X_i<u$ is $1/(u-l)$ for $l<x_i<u$ and then you calculate the expected value of that. But, why is the conditional distribution uniform with pdf $1/(u-l)$?

Comment: The probability that $X_i$ will be equal to the given order statistic is $\frac{1}{n}$ - one of the variables from the sequence of i.i.d. random variables will always be equal to the order statistic.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying, the notation $P(X_{i} = X_{(1)})$ refers to the probability of the event in which one random variable $X_i$ is equal to the order statistic $X_{(1)}$ and not the probability of $X_{i}$ taking on a particular value between $\theta-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\theta+\frac{1}{2}$, which is ofcourse zero, right? How about the expectation part, how did you obtain $\frac{l+u}{2}$?

Comment: Just from the expectation of a uniform random variable - the conditional distribution should be uniform on $(l, u)$.

Comment: oh, sorry - I accidentally put $b$ for bound instead of $u$ for upper twice. that may have been confusing.

Comment: Let's assume $b-a=1$ for simplicity, as in our case. $f(x \ | x \ \in [c, d]) = \frac{f(x)}{P(x \in [c, d])} = \frac{1}{(d - c)}$

Comment: Haha, yes, I just realized that after your comment! So silly of me.