# Rao-Blackwellize an estimator of uniform distribution

Tags: statistics

I am trying to use the Rao-Blackwell theorem to arrive at a better estimate for $\theta$ than $\bar{X}$ given that $X \sim U[\theta-0.5,\theta-0.5]$ and sufficient statistic $T(X) = (X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ . This is very similar to another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439929/rao-blackwells-theorem-for-uniform-distribution) asked here, so I can see what the answer should be, but I am still confused. I would like to do the following, although I can see that this brings me back to where I've started:
 \begin{align*}
E[\bar{X} | T(X) ]  &= E[X_i | X_{(1)} = x_l, X_{(n)} = x_u] \\
&= E[X_i | X_{i} = x_l] \times P(X_i = x_l)  \\
&\text{      } + E[X_i |  X_{i} = x_u] \times P(X_i = x_u) \\
&\text{      } + E[X_i |  X_{i} \notin \{x_l, x_u \}] \times P(X_i \notin \{x_l, x_u \}) \\
&= x_l \frac{1}{n} + x_u \frac{1}{n} + \frac{\sum_{x=1}^n x_i - x_l - x_u}{n-2}\times \frac{n-2}{n} \\
&= \bar{X}
\end{align*}
I suppose my question can be reduced to why does $E[X_i |  X_{i} \notin \{x_l, x_u \}] = \frac{x_u - x_l}{2}$? (Assuming I did everything else right.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the question you state in the end is not exactly the right one. It should be something like

> Why does $\mathbb E[X_i | X_i \in (x_l,x_u)]=\frac{x_u+x_l}{2}$.

This is because we know that $X_i\notin \lbrace X_{(1)}, X_{(n)}\rbrace$ and $X_i\in [X_{(1)},X_{(n)}]$.

Now if you agree with that, observe that any uniform random variable $X\sim U(\mathcal A)$, where $\mathcal A$ is closed, has the property that for any set $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal C$, $\mathbb P (X\in\mathcal B | X\in\mathcal C)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X\in\mathcal B, X\in\mathcal C)}{\mathbb{P}(X\in\mathcal C)}=\frac{\lvert A\cap B \cap C\rvert}{\lvert A \cap C\rvert}$ which makes it a uniform distribution over the set $\mathcal A \cap \mathcal C$.
In your case, $\mathcal A=[\theta - 0.5, \theta+0.5]\supseteq [x_l,x_u] = \mathcal C$ and so the conditional distribution is uniform over $\mathcal A \cap \mathcal C=[x_l,x_u]$, at this point there is no conditioning and so the expectation is
\begin{align*}
\int_{x_l}^{x_u} \frac{x}{x_u-x_l} dx &= \left[ \frac{x^2}{2(x_u-x_l)} \right]_{x_l}^{x_u}\\
&=\frac{x_u^2-x_l^2}{2(x_u-x_l)}\\
&=\frac{(x_u-x_l)(x_u+x_l)}{2(x_u-x_l)}\\
&=\frac{x_u+x_l}{2}
\end{align*}

---

To go back to your Rao-Blackwellization, you get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\bar X|X_{(1)},X_{(n)}] &= \frac{X_{(1)}}{n} + \frac{X_{(n)}}{n} + \frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2} \cdot \frac{n-2}{n}\\
&=\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}
\end{align*}

Which in the end is an UMVUE estimator of $\theta$ because $(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ is both sufficient and complete.

Comment: Thank you! That is a helpful correction in notation, and again, I can see how you are right, but isn't your last step just $X \sim U[x_l, x_u] \implies E[X_i] = \frac{x_u - x_l}{2}$. It's certainly valid, but I feel uncomfortable asserting it because the point of the exercise seems to be to show that.

Comment: Yes you are right, by the way there were a typo, the expectation should be the mean between $x_u$ and $x_l$ intuitively, I added a derivation for this.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now, thank you!

Comment: I don't think $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is complete.