# Rao Blackwell. Finding unbiased estimator help

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

I have done many problems with the Rao Blackwell Theory and finding an unbiased estimator, but this question has stumped me a little

Question

$Uniform(\theta, 3\theta)|\theta > 0$

$g_{\theta}(x) = \frac{1}{2\theta}$ $\theta\leq x\leq 3\theta$

Given $\hat{\theta}_{MOM} = \frac{1}{2}\bar{X}$ as unbiased for $\theta$

$T(\vec{X}) = (X_{1}, X_{n})$ is a sufficient statistic

Find using Rao-Blackwell, an unbiased estimator that is uniformly better than $\hat{\theta_{MOM}}$

But I am lost when we have a two-dimensional sufficient statistic instead of one.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you wrote down the problem correctly? $$T(X_1,...,X_n)=(X_1,X_n)$$ isn't necessarily sufficient since the conditional distribution $(X_1,...,X_n)|T(X_1,...,X_n)=(x_1,x_n)$ depends on $\theta$ when $n>2$.

Comment: I assume you meant $T=(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$. Then looks like you would end up with

$$E\left[\frac12\overline X\mid T \right]=\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{4}$$

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2001780/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2439929/321264.